# Epics not triggering in Redux observable with Redux toolkit

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux-toolkit, redux-observable

I tried to follow the documentation and this is what I did

middleware/index.ts

```
import { combineEpics } from "redux-observable";
import userEpic from "./userEpic";

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    userEpic,
);
```

store.ts

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable";
import { rootEpic } from "../middleware";
import userReducer from "./reducers/userSlice";

const rootReducer = {
  user: userReducer,
};
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(epicMiddleware),
});

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

export type RootStateType = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatchType = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

actions.ts

```
export const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";
export const loginUser = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_USER,
  } as const;
};
export type LoginUserAction = ReturnType<typeof loginUser>;
```

userEpic.ts (this is where the API call should be but I made this way just to test if it is working)

```
import { Action } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { combineEpics, ofType } from "redux-observable";
import { LOGIN_USER } from "./actions";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { setUserData } from "../../redux/reducers/userSlice";

const fetchUserEpic = (action$: Observable<Action>) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOGIN_USER),
    map(() =>
      setUserData({
        id: 12,
        name: "test",
        surname: "test",
        username: "test",
        refreshToken: "test",
        accessToken: "test",
      })
    )
  );
};

export default combineEpics(fetchUserEpic);
```

userSlice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { FetchStatus } from "../../modules/types";
import { RootStateType } from "../store";

type UserType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  username: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  accessToken: string;
};

type UserStateType = {
  user: UserType | null;
  userFetchStatus: FetchStatus;
};

const initialUserState: UserStateType = {
  user: null,
  userFetchStatus: FetchStatus.success,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialUserState,
  reducers: {
    setUserData: (state, action: PayloadAction<UserType>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.userFetchStatus = FetchStatus.success;
    },
    setUserFetchingStatus: (state, action: PayloadAction<FetchStatus>) => {
      state.userFetchStatus = action.payload;
    },
    clearUserData: () => {
      return initialUserState;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addDefaultCase((state) => {
      return state;
    });
  },
});

export const { setUserData, clearUserData } = userSlice.actions;

export const getUserData = (state: RootStateType) => state.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

And I have some component where I trigger `loginUser` and then try to console log it from the redux

component.ts

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
const user = useAppSelector(getUserData);
console.log(user)
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => dispatch(loginUser)}>
//...
```

package.json

```
  "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
  "redux": "^4.2.0",
  "redux-observable": "^2.0.0"
```

Looks like the redux store is not changing, `loginUser` action is triggering but looks like `ofType(LOGIN_USER)` is not catching it, I saw in some other thread and documentation to use `filter(actionFunction.match),` instead of `ofType`, but I think that is only for redux actions? And when I use the filter I get an error that is deprecated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying that `LOGIN_USER` is not a Redux action? Where is it created, where is it dispatched?

Comment: I meant it's not created with `createSlice`. I cannot use `loginUser.match` because the `match` doesn't exist there.

Comment: How is it created then? This is literally the most important part of your code and you are omitting it.

Comment: Oh, I thought I provided it, my bad. I edited the post. It's in `actions.ts` that is in the same folder as `userEpic.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your action creator:

`dispatch(loginUser())`, not `dispatch(loginUser)`.

Apart from that, you should definitely not be writing that action creator by hand - if you don't want to make it with `createSlice`, at least use `createAction` for it.

`export const loginUser = createAction('user/login')`.

Then you can also use `filter(loginUser.match)` with it.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that. It is my first time using redux-observable and also toolkit. I will use `createAction` but I saw in another project that actions for storing data in redux are in one file (like `setUserData`) and for epics (`loginUser` where I need to call API) are in another. Could I just move my epics actions to `userSlice` and `createSlice`. Would that be better?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, so it's probably just a choice of code style. Generally, redux-observable is kind of an oddball choice in 2022, especially for something like "just api calls". Have you tried doing your api calls just in the normal ways laid out in the Redux tutorial (chapters 5,7 and 8) https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: I saw the `createAsyncThunk`, it looks interesting but I thought to try to practice redux-observable. Tried redux-saga but didn't really like it.

Comment: Both redux-observable and redux-saga are not really what we as the Redux team recommend for most codebases - they are very oversized solutions and are mostly used for problems that don't need them. I'd say that less than 5% of all applications ever have a need for one of both. You should get far enough with thunks, RTK Query for data fetching and the RTK listenerMiddleware if you ever need to react to actions. Also see https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#use-thunks-for-async-logic

Comment: Co-creator of redux-observable here. I agree it’s very likely unnecessary complexity for a vast majority of apps. If it’s a personal project for learning then of course by all means have fun though!